# Create PDF, insert it in another and merge pages - ruby PDF tool?

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

I am searching for a tool for ruby, that allows me to:

1. Create pdf with images, texts and barcodes (I use [barby](https://github.com/toretore/barby)). This document has a very precise specification – all elements have to be placed correctly.
2. Take that pdf, rotate, scale and place it in another pdf page.
3. Merge several pdf pages.

PDFlib was perfect for this and allowed to do all the three steps, but it's too expensive... The same reason keeps me away form checking princely. My invesitigation led me to the following possible solutions:

1 .
- prawn?
- wicked PDF?
- PDFkit?

2 . ???

3 .
- pdf-merger?
- pdf toolkit?

Is there something else that I missed? Which option could be the best? Which lib can support step 2?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've never used it, but I hear that Prawn is really excellent and probably the best option. Hopefully someone with experience will answer you.

Answer (score 0):

pdfkit should be able to handle all the items you mention.  I've had great luck with it. If you can lay it out with html/css, you can make it a pdf.  You can handle scaling and rotation in your environment.rb by passing params to the pdfkit middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com) to create the PDF with the images and [CombinePDF](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) to Rotateit, scale it and place it within a different PDF.

(I'm biased, being CombinePDF's author)