# What gem should i use to manipulate pdf files in ruby?

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, rubygems, pdf-rendering

I need to create a new pdf file from other pdf files, for example i have
file1.pdf, file2.pdf
need to create a new_file.pdf, that contains page 1, 4, 6 from file1.pdf, and 1, 3, 4 from file2.pdf.
I need to get the pages as they are, not parse them as texts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create PDF, insert it in another and merge pages - ruby PDF tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379790/create-pdf-insert-it-in-another-and-merge-pages-ruby-pdf-tool)

Answer (score 0):

[How to generate PDF from markdown using pure ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377849/how-to-generate-pdf-from-markdown-using-pure-ruby)

[How do you combine PDFs in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499563/how-do-you-combine-pdfs-in-ruby)

These are answers to your question.

Comment: From what I understood prawn is only to create a new pdf not manipulating a saved pdf, and the pdf-merge only merge all pages from one file to another